# Getting multiple value's from same database row

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks for the time to read my question. I have a form on my website (Wordpress wp_forms) this generates a database entry `wp_wpforms_entry_fields` where the entries for the form are stored. My form contains three fields (Name, Email address and a Yes or No question).

In my database this creates the following table:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is get the `field_id` from `1` and `3`. So with my SQL I do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields 
    WHERE field_id = 1";
```

But this only selects the value from `field_id 1` what I would like is to also have the value from `WHERE field_id 3 = Yes`. This way I can show the names of people who gave a positive answer to the question.

I have no idea where to start, this is probably not as difficult as I'm making it. But doing:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM wp_wpforms_entry_fields 
    WHERE field_id = 1 
        AND field_id = 3 
        AND IS Yes";
```

Surely doesn't work... thanks again for reading.

PS. I've left out the database connection rules because the connection works, I can retrieve data based on the first `SELECT`. But I can't seem to get the separation between Yes and No.

Comment: Then you need to select where `entry_id = 8`.

Comment: @u_mulder `entry_id` does not seem to have any relation with `field_id`

Comment: @ZainFarooq I presume __entry__ in an entity which holds all fields result for certain action.

Comment: @u_mulder Then we don't need **entry** column at all

Comment: Maybe you're right. If OP needs all actions with `yes` answer, `entry_id` is not needed.

Comment: `entry_id` may vary. OP has shown us *some* records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to join the table to itself:

```
select f1.value as name
from wp_wpforms_entry_fields f1
    inner join wp_wpforms_entry_fields f3 on (f1.entry_id = f3.entry_id and f3.field_id = 3)
where f1.field_id = 1 and f3.value = 'Yes'
```

In plain text, you're looking for names of entries, where a row for `field_id` 3 with same `entry_id` says `'Yes'`.

Alternatively, with a subquery:

```
select value as name
from wp_wpforms_entry_fields f1
where field_id = 1
    and entry_id in (
        select entry_id from wp_wpforms_entry_fields f3 where field_id = 3 and value = 'Yes'
    )
```

Here we select a list of `entry_id`s for which there is 'Yes' in field 3, and then we select values of field 1 for those entries whose `entry_id` is on that first list.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is getting me every value from all table rows (so this shows me Name, E-mail address and Yes or NO). How do I only show the Name field if field_id 3 is Yes?

Comment: Fixed the query, I was missing some conditions.

Comment: This is going somewhere, I really appreciate your help. Final question because it's almost working. How do I echo the `value` from `field_id 1`.  Because `echo "-" . $row["value"]. "<br>";` does give me one value but echo's no values...

Comment: That query gives the result an alias `name`, so `$row["name"]`.

Comment: Great stuff! This is working! Thanks a million! One final question, if you don't mind. Can I use this query to make a count for everybody that said yes? like `select COUNT(value) as name`

Comment: `select COUNT(f1.value) as name from wp_wpforms_entry_fields f1 inner join wp_wpforms_entry_fields f3 on (f1.entry_id = f3.entry_id and f3.field_id = 3) where f1.field_id = 1 and f3.value = 'Ja'` works. So I've solved my own question. Thanks again

Comment: If you want to just count everybody who said 'Ja', it's far simpler, because you don't need their names: `select count(1) from wp_wpforms_entry_fields where field_id = 3 and value = 'Ja'` (assuming you don't allow multiple answers per person).